# How to remove previous path data while transion using D3.js drawing a ECG wave chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, path

The purpose is to draw a ECG-wave-like chart indicating current network flood and the chart keep  transiting to the left and redraw with new data fetched by ajax in the viewport.

But i don't know how to remove previous path nodes when these nodes transits out of the viewport.

```
var wrapperWidth = 800;
var wrapperHeight = 400;

var margin = { top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 0 },
    width = wrapperWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = wrapperHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var xAxisScale = 15;
var svg;

var ECG = {
    begin: function () {
        var list = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5];
        svg = d3.select(".jke-ecgChart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", wrapperWidth)
            .attr("height", wrapperHeight);
        this.sliceData(list);
    },
    sliceData: function (list) {
        var index = 0;

    // draw the path that in current viewport
    this.drawECG(list.slice(index, 10).map(function(item, index) {
        return {
            value: item.lTagIndex || 0,
            title: item.sTagName || ''
        }
    }));

    // // draw the right part path that will tansition to viewport
    // 
    // index+=10;
    // this.drawECG(list.slice(index, index+10).map(function(item, index) {
    //     return {
    //         value: item.lTagIndex || 0,
    //         title: item.sTagName || ''
    //     }
    // }));
  },
  drawECG: function(data) {
    // d3.shuffle(data);

    var valueData = [];
    // format the data
    data.forEach(function(d, index) {
        d.index = index;
        valueData.push(d.value);
    });

    var mean = d3.mean(valueData);
    var minMax = d3.extent(valueData);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // define the line
    var valueline = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) {
            return d.index * xAxisScale;
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return y(d.value - mean);
        });

    // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var group = svg
        .attr("width", wrapperWidth)
        .attr("height", wrapperHeight)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    y.domain([(minMax[0] - mean), (minMax[1] - mean)]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    group.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline);

    var showTextData = data.filter(function (textData, index) {
        if (data[index-1] && data[index+1]) {

            if(data[index-1].value < textData.value && data[index+1].value < textData.value) {
                return true;
            }
            if(data[index-1].value > textData.value && data[index+1].value > textData.value) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    group.transition()
        .duration(13000)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + -wrapperWidth + ", 0)")
        .style("fill", "red")
        .remove();

    group.append("g")
        .attr("class", "states-names")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(showTextData)
        .enter()
        .append("svg:text")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.title;
        })
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.index * xAxisScale;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.value - mean);
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr('fill', 'white');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to remove the last created group before appending path and other related DOMs to it.

```
//remove the group
svg.select("g").remove();//ADD THIS LINE

//create a group and add line and other dom to it.
var group = svg
    .attr("width", wrapperWidth)
    .attr("height", wrapperHeight)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Another question,I do i connect the last node of the last group with the first node of the newly created group and make it like a continuous line ?

Comment: don't worry the line will be generated afresh as per the data you passing in the `drawECG` function

Comment: I want to draw a dynamic ECG wave, so the animation and fluidity is the point but i do't know how to do it

Comment: check  this example http://plnkr.co/edit/F1TCnDjxvTpFDTY8fK9w?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Normally an ECG will maintain the old recorded data and sweep over it, which removes the old data as the new data is drawn. Here is an example of how you would do that by using two separate paths, and two clip paths.

As new data is drawn, you can reduce the size of the old clip path rectangle, and translate it, so it gives you the effect of the data being removed. Here's an example I created.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seancronin/5Ltxj428/)

```
    var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
};
var xIndex = 0;
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var data = [];
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 200]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([height, 0]);
var count = 0;
var lineToDraw;

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
      return x(d.x);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return y(d.y);
    });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Render two slip paths. One will be drawn as the other is wiped. To create the wipe 
effect, I simply reduce the size of the clip path and translate it.
var clipPath1 = svg.append("defs")
      .append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip1");

var clipPath2 = svg.append("defs")
      .append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip2");

var clipRect1 = clipPath1.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", 0)
        .attr("height", height);

var clipRect2 = clipPath2.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", 0)
        .attr("height", height);

// Append two paths. One path will be used to draw on while the other will be the previously drawn path.
var path1 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "g1")
    .append("path") // Add the valueline path.
    .attr("class", "line1")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip1)")
    .data([data])
    .attr("d", valueline);

var path2 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "g2")
    .append("path")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip2)")// Add the valueline path.
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line2")
    .attr("d", valueline);

// Add the x and y axis.
svg.append("g") 
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g") 
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

// An interval that adds a data point every 5 milliseconds
setInterval(function() 
{ 
  var point = {
    x: xIndex,
    y: Math.abs(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(100)))
  };

  data.push(point);
  xIndex++;
  addData(); 

}, 5);

function addData() 
{

  if (data.length === 200) 
  {
    count++;
    xIndex = 0;
    data =[]
    if (lineToDraw !== undefined) 
    {
      if (lineToDraw === ".line1") 
      {
        clipRect2.attr("width", "0");
        clipRect2.attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)");
      } 
      else 
      {
        clipRect1.attr("width", "0");
        clipRect1.attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)");
      }
    }
  }


  lineToDraw = count % 2 === 0 ? ".line1" : ".line2";

  var increment = x(data.length);
  var newWidth = width - increment;

  if (lineToDraw === ".line1") 
  {
      clipRect1.attr("width", increment);
      clipRect2.attr("width", newWidth);
      clipRect2.attr("transform", "translate(" + increment + ", 0)");
  } 
  else 
  {
      clipRect2.attr("width", increment);
      clipRect1.attr("width", newWidth);
      clipRect1.attr("transform", "translate(" +increment + ", 0)");
  }

  svg.select(lineToDraw)  
    .data([data])
    .attr("d", valueline);

}
```